# How do I make an iFrame reload the page it is on when the iframe loads a specific page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am using a wyswyg based site "builder" in order to make a site as I am not very familiar with any sort of web code. The builder has locked their system pages from any sort of modification due to "security issues". What I want to do is load the login and register tables into a iFrame that is nested inside of an html module with a div tag. This actually works very well. The issue I have now is that the whole thing seems to hang once the needed action is completed. What I would like to be able to do is have the whole page (not just the iFrame) reload once the iframe has gone to a specific url. I understand that javascript may be able to allow me to do this, but I'm at a loss as to how to make it work. I have manually tested refreshing the page and that works fine. So, if I could just automate that in some way this would probably work as intended. Here is the code my partner and I have cobbled together to load the section of the page we want to be visible, what now?

```html
<div style="border: 0px solid #FFF; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 300px; margin-top:   30px; margin-bottom: 30px; max-width: 406px; height: 230px; position: relative;">
<form method="POST" action="getForm.php">
<iframe id="login" scrolling="no" src="http://lumina-fc.com/login" style="position: relative; margin-left: -255px; height: 270px; margin-top: -50px; width: 700px;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the following JavaScript from the iframe:

```
window.top.reload();
```

Comment: Would something like this work, or am I misunderstanding?

'<script>
function GetIFrameUrl()
{
   if document.getElementById('login') = "link" {
window.top.reload();}
)
</script>'

Comment: Nope, are you in control of the pages which are loaded in the iframe?

Comment: Yes, all of the pages being dealt with are from the same domain. The domain and site,as a whole, are mine.

Comment: Ok, you should invoke the JavaScript snippet on the page which is being load, not the one containing the iframe.

Comment: I am not able to do that, which was the problem to start with. So, is there no solution for this then?